# ASP.NET Grid for .NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datagrid, datagridview, grid

Does anybody know of a good asp.net grid for .NET 2.0 that has the following:

- Paging
- Sorting for columns
- Clickable rows that allows you to view the details of that row.
- Ajax enabled.
- that is preferably free :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is by far the best, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah that is a nice grid.  Thanks. Do you know of any decent free ones out there? The best one I saw so far is webgrid http://www.webgrid.com/.